# When a composite component containing JS code is rendered multiple times, JS works only on last component

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I have a composite component that is using a PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneMenu>` defined like:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="inOut" onchange="inOutChanged()">
  ..
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I then have a JavaScript file that is included as part of the component that defines the 
`inOutChanged()` function like

```
function inOutChanged() {
  var inOut = $({cc.clientId}:inOut);
  if(inOut.val() == "INC") {
    slider.addClass("includedInRange");
  }
}
```

This composite component works fine when there is only one on the page.  The problem is that I need to have 4 of them on the page.  So, when I change the select of one composite component it is changing the slider class of the last component.  I believe this is because there are in effect 4 `inOutChanged()` functions that are all defined within the page.

Is there a way to either scope the function or name it uniquely so that they won't stomp on each other?

Comment: You're misinterpreting the problem. First, how and where have you declared the `slider` variable? It look namely much like that you've just overridden the variable's value everytime so that it end up holding the last assigned value. All with all, I have the impression that you actually meant "composite component" when you said "component"? This way the question would make much more sense.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, it is a composite component. The slider variable is also declared using a similair approach with cc.clientId. It is possible that I've overridden the slider variable. I think I'll have to try the approach you suggested in your answer maybe as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because you redeclared and reassigned the same JavaScript variable `slider` in the global scope. You need to move the declaration of `slider` to inside the function.

Redeclaring exactly the same function doesn't harm, but is plain inefficient and not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You should move the function into its own `.js` file and use `<h:outputScript>` to include it. JSF will ultimately include it only once. Then, alter the function accordingly to take variables as arguments.

Something like this

```
<h:outputScript library="composite" name="some.js" target="head" />
...
<h:panelGroup id="...">
    <p:selectOneMenu ... onchange="inOutChanged(this)">
        ...
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    ...
    <p:slider ... />
</h:panelGroup>
```

with this inside `/resources/composite/some.js` (provided that `/resoruces/composite` contains your composite component XHTML file)

```
function inOutChanged(menuElement) {
    var $menu = $(menuElement);
    if ($menu.val() == "INC") {
        $menu.parent().find(".ui-slider").addClass("includedInRange");
    }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't because of my slider variable.  It was declared within my function so it should have been unique.  However, I did use both your approach of making a separate function that was included and using this + a parent selector.  I had to mess with the parent selector since PrimeFaces adds several layers of divs between the panelgroup and the selectOneMenu.  But this got me moving along.

Comment: You can also use `.closest()` to get the closest parent matching the given selector.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this)` selector within your change event listener:

```
$(".inOut").change(function(){
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if(sel == 'INC') {
        //find slider and add class
    }
});
```

Note that I bound onchange event listeners outside the scope of the component, and found components basing on attached CSS class. This could be done within `$(document).ready()`.

Of course, you can use client ids in the JS function or bind that function to a component's attribute as well.

Comment: I took an approach similar.  But, BalusC's answer was more useful.